# R: Dual y-axis panel.grid.major not aligning

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://drawar.github.io/posts/dual-y-axis-ggplot2/) on how to create a dual y-axis plot (yes, I know). My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/tchakravarty/d4ead37873dbf356df1ce2954e3d3f8d).

However, in the output some of the major grid lines are slightly misaligned (see the red box), whereas some of them are perfectly aligned. I am not sure what is causing this dilation of one of the plots. I rewrote the code on that site to understand it better and have possibly introduced a bug somewhere.

[image]

An easy fix would be to turn off grid lines on one of the plots, but that seems to be hiding the problem rather than fixing it.

---

## Edit:

I tried running [the original code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drawar/drawar.github.io/master/_posts/lineplot.R) here unchanged, and I ran into the following error on line 130.

```
> ticks$grobs[[1]]$x <- ticks$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + tml
Error in Ops.unit(ticks$grobs[[1]]$x, unit(1, "npc")) : 
  both operands must be units
```

So, I cannot check if the issue is a bug that I have introduced while transcription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the `gist` doesn't run (and it's also a bit complicated).

To understand why the lines aren't aligned, consider this example:

- axis1: range: 0 - 1. The value of 0.5 is mid-way between 0 and 1.
- axis2: range: 0 - 10. The value of 5 is mid-way between 0 and 10.

Now in your graph you have (something like)

- axis1: range: 0 - 1.1. The value of 0.5 is 0.5/1.1 = 0.45 between 0 and 1.
- axis2: range: 0 - 10.1. The value of 5 is 5/10.1 = 0.495 between 0 and 10.
- Result: mis-aligned lines.

You shouldn't add a constant to each axis, the value needs to be proportional to the scale.

Comment: Can you specify at what point the code in the gist fails for you?

Comment: You're missing packages ("dplyr`) and you don't give the colours.

Comment: Updated the code. Let me know if you have any further issues in running the code.

Comment: nop, ´ticks$grobs[[1]]$x <- ticks$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + tml
Error in Ops.unit(ticks$grobs[[1]]$x, unit(1, "npc")) : 
  both operands must be units´